# Sales rank of a subcategory through amazon product api (preferably in python using bottlenose)

Tags: python, amazon-product-api, bottlenose

I am trying to retrieve Product subcategories sales rank (If it is applicable) and this is the script that I have written in Python

```
amazon=bottlenose.Amazon('AmazonCredentials',MaxQPS=0.9)
response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId="B007SNQ4FM", ResponseGroup="Large", )
x = etree.XML(response)
string_to_store=etree.tostring(x, pretty_print = True)
print string_to_store
```

The response that I Got from Amazon

```
..............
................
<SalesRank>12677</SalesRank>
  <SmallImage>
    <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31Nk86so5xL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
    <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
    <Width Units="pixels">26</Width>
  </SmallImage>
..........
..........
```

The actual response can be seen here : http://pastebin.com/rCUKCbas

The original page (ie., Detailed page url) url: 
    [http://www.amazon.com/Luma-Comfort-EC45S-Evaporative-Cooling/dp/B007SNQ4FM%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAICPZU6FE2WKAQMZQ%26tag%3Drelierscom-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB007SNQ4FM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007SNQ4FM)

The Product details from the web:

```
ASIN: B007SNQ4FM
Item model number: EC45S
Average Customer Review:  2.4 out of 5 stars  See all reviews (59 customer reviews)
Amazon Best Sellers Rank: #12,677 in Home & Kitchen (See Top 100 in Home & Kitchen)
#1 in Home Improvement > Appliances > Range Hoods
#18 in Home & Kitchen > Heating, Cooling & Air Quality > Air Conditioners & Accessories     > Portable
```

In the above we can see it is having three rankings under different categories, but where as by using product api i am able to get only one rank (12,677), but how could I retrieve the other two rankings.

Answer (score 1):

I was also hoping for an answer on this post since I'm looking for the same solution.

So far all I've found on the web is [this Amazon Forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=123983) Saying that it can't be done. 
If I find an answer I'll come back and post it.